# OSClass - Item does not get added when using Chrome, but works in Firefox

Tags: osclass

Using OSclass322 and
Chrome 29

Had this problem and could not resolve it so OK - reinstalled plain vanilla 322 version. 
Added no plugins/made no changes.
Cannot add item using Chrome or internet Explorer - can add item using Firefox.

Under Chrome - it happily runs through the item_add script.
I receive an email that says the item has been added - but gives an erroneous url ending in `/index.php?page=item&id=0`.
It then updates the category count as though an item had been added to the db using the chosen category. It does not add the item to the items table

Will work using localhost - using Chrome - will not work on webserver using Chrome.
Will work using Firefox (25) on localhost and webserver.

website currently located at http://buyitsellitswapit.net/

I have tried adding an item either as registered user, or as unregistered and it makes no difference.

Would be very grateful if someone could point me to where this script is failing please.

Edit update...after further testing
This has been quite strange - fails under Ubuntu 13.10/Chrome 29, but works in Firefox and Chromium (30)
Works when I use a WinXP/Chrome and WinXP/IE in VirtualBox under Ubuntu
Works on my son's machine - Win8/Chrome and IE

Just hope not too many clients are using Ubuntu and Chrome together.